# Add Rows in Data Table with variable number of Columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-visualization

I am using the Google Chart Library to create a line chart. I need to dynamically add columns and rows. Here is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < uniquedim2.length; i++){
                  data.addColumn('number', uniquedim2[i]);
              }
for(var i = 0; i < dimensions1.length; i++){
              data.addRow([
                uniquedim1[i], 
                groupeddataArray[0][i],
                groupeddataArray[1][i],
                groupeddataArray[2][i],
              ]);
          }
```

How do I make it so that instead of repeating and hard coding the variable "groupeddataArray" it would repeat based on the length of "uniquedim2".

So for example if the length of "uniquedim2" is 5 then this code will output:

```
for(var i = 0; i < dimensions1.length; i++){
              data.addRow([
                uniquedim1[i], 
                groupeddataArray[0][i],
                groupeddataArray[1][i],
                groupeddataArray[2][i],
                groupeddataArray[3][i],
                groupeddataArray[4][i],

              ]);
          }
```

Thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
    var row = [uniquedim1[i]];
    for (var j = 0; j < groupedDataArray.length; j++) {
        row.push(groupedDataArray[j][i]);
    }
    data.addRow(row);
}
```

The above should work for your case. You simply create an array called `row` that initially stores the current value of `uniqueddim1`. Then you create a loop that iterates through your `groupedDataArray` and append the values using the indices of both loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a life saver (: